Nash equilibrium details for Leduc Hold'em
Can anyone point me to the details of a verified Nash equilibrium for Leduc Hold'em? I have an implementation of Counterfactual Regret Minimization (CFR) that I am testing with Leduc, and would like to know precisely what the optimum strategy is. In particular, I would like to know the expected utility for the first player, and the strategy for each of the 288 information sets in the game. (I realize that there might be more than one Nash strategy, but they should all agree on the expected utility, at least.)
Leduc Hold'em is described in this paper, which claims to have exactly computed an optimum strategy ("Opti") for the game. Unfortunately, the paper doesn't provide any more details about this strategy. There are also several implementations of CFR for Leduc scattered around GitHub, but they don't seem to converge on the same expected utility, so it's impossible to know which ones, if any, are correct.

FWIW, here are my results after evaluating 500,000,000 games via CFR:
Average game value for first player: -0.08553

Strategy:
J          :    x: 0.92550, b: 0.07450
J b        :    f: 0.81907, c: 0.12621, r: 0.05472
J br       :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
J x        :    x: 0.70360, b: 0.29640
J xb       :    f: 0.94674, c: 0.03491, r: 0.01835
J xbr      :    f: 0.00001, c: 0.99999
JJ bcd     :    x: 0.02729, b: 0.97271
JJ bcdb    :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
JJ bcdbr   :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
JJ bcdx    :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
JJ bcdxb   :    f: 0.00002, c: 0.00002, r: 0.99997
JJ bcdxbr  :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
JJ brcd    :    x: 0.00415, b: 0.99585
JJ brcdb   :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00001, r: 0.99999
JJ brcdbr  :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
JJ brcdx   :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
JJ brcdxb  :    f: 0.00006, c: 0.00006, r: 0.99989
JJ brcdxbr :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
JJ xbcd    :    x: 0.04758, b: 0.95242
JJ xbcdb   :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
JJ xbcdbr  :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
JJ xbcdx   :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
JJ xbcdxb  :    f: 0.00001, c: 0.00001, r: 0.99998
JJ xbcdxbr :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
JJ xbrcd   :    x: 0.00001, b: 0.99999
JJ xbrcdb  :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
JJ xbrcdbr :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
JJ xbrcdx  :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
JJ xbrcdxb :    f: 0.09853, c: 0.09853, r: 0.80294
JJ xbrcdxbr:    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
JJ xxd     :    x: 0.99999, b: 0.00001
JJ xxdb    :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.26824, r: 0.73176
JJ xxdbr   :    f: 0.00651, c: 0.99349
JJ xxdx    :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
JJ xxdxb   :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
JJ xxdxbr  :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
JK bcd     :    x: 0.00118, b: 0.99882
JK bcdb    :    f: 0.63107, c: 0.00000, r: 0.36893
JK bcdbr   :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JK bcdx    :    x: 0.60945, b: 0.39055
JK bcdxb   :    f: 0.05134, c: 0.00051, r: 0.94815
JK bcdxbr  :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JK brcd    :    x: 0.45401, b: 0.54599
JK brcdb   :    f: 0.70676, c: 0.00000, r: 0.29324
JK brcdbr  :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JK brcdx   :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
JK brcdxb  :    f: 0.05933, c: 0.00000, r: 0.94067
JK brcdxbr :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JK xbcd    :    x: 0.96385, b: 0.03615
JK xbcdb   :    f: 0.95707, c: 0.00000, r: 0.04293
JK xbcdbr  :    f: 0.99998, c: 0.00002
JK xbcdx   :    x: 0.44976, b: 0.55024
JK xbcdxb  :    f: 0.99010, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00990
JK xbcdxbr :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JK xbrcd   :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
JK xbrcdb  :    f: 0.79719, c: 0.00001, r: 0.20280
JK xbrcdbr :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JK xbrcdx  :    x: 0.46781, b: 0.53219
JK xbrcdxb :    f: 0.33333, c: 0.33333, r: 0.33333
JK xbrcdxbr:    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JK xxd     :    x: 0.92515, b: 0.07485
JK xxdb    :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00000
JK xxdbr   :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JK xxdx    :    x: 0.99234, b: 0.00766
JK xxdxb   :    f: 0.99990, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00010
JK xxdxbr  :    f: 0.98269, c: 0.01731
JQ bcd     :    x: 0.00022, b: 0.99978
JQ bcdb    :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00000
JQ bcdbr   :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JQ bcdx    :    x: 0.00061, b: 0.99939
JQ bcdxb   :    f: 0.99489, c: 0.00255, r: 0.00255
JQ bcdxbr  :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JQ brcd    :    x: 0.88249, b: 0.11751
JQ brcdb   :    f: 0.57337, c: 0.00000, r: 0.42662
JQ brcdbr  :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JQ brcdx   :    x: 0.99931, b: 0.00069
JQ brcdxb  :    f: 0.99978, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00022
JQ brcdxbr :    f: 0.99911, c: 0.00089
JQ xbcd    :    x: 0.00592, b: 0.99408
JQ xbcdb   :    f: 0.86864, c: 0.00000, r: 0.13136
JQ xbcdbr  :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JQ xbcdx   :    x: 0.60575, b: 0.39425
JQ xbcdxb  :    f: 0.12239, c: 0.00007, r: 0.87753
JQ xbcdxbr :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JQ xbrcd   :    x: 0.99389, b: 0.00611
JQ xbrcdb  :    f: 0.67335, c: 0.00001, r: 0.32664
JQ xbrcdbr :    f: 0.99980, c: 0.00020
JQ xbrcdx  :    x: 0.95796, b: 0.04204
JQ xbrcdxb :    f: 0.80249, c: 0.00000, r: 0.19751
JQ xbrcdxbr:    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JQ xxd     :    x: 0.80872, b: 0.19128
JQ xxdb    :    f: 0.96453, c: 0.00000, r: 0.03547
JQ xxdbr   :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
JQ xxdx    :    x: 0.92860, b: 0.07140
JQ xxdxb   :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00000
JQ xxdxbr  :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
K          :    x: 0.24597, b: 0.75403
K b        :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.42031, r: 0.57969
K br       :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
K x        :    x: 0.00009, b: 0.99991
K xb       :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.31237, r: 0.68763
K xbr      :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KJ bcd     :    x: 0.92081, b: 0.07919
KJ bcdb    :    f: 0.24703, c: 0.72812, r: 0.02486
KJ bcdbr   :    f: 0.68202, c: 0.31798
KJ bcdx    :    x: 0.51593, b: 0.48407
KJ bcdxb   :    f: 0.00700, c: 0.99062, r: 0.00238
KJ bcdxbr  :    f: 0.31586, c: 0.68414
KJ brcd    :    x: 0.91879, b: 0.08121
KJ brcdb   :    f: 0.07363, c: 0.88478, r: 0.04158
KJ brcdbr  :    f: 0.51933, c: 0.48067
KJ brcdx   :    x: 0.69832, b: 0.30168
KJ brcdxb  :    f: 0.00035, c: 0.99963, r: 0.00003
KJ brcdxbr :    f: 0.00752, c: 0.99248
KJ xbcd    :    x: 0.99999, b: 0.00001
KJ xbcdb   :    f: 0.26559, c: 0.73441, r: 0.00000
KJ xbcdbr  :    f: 0.02292, c: 0.97708
KJ xbcdx   :    x: 0.87021, b: 0.12979
KJ xbcdxb  :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.99998, r: 0.00002
KJ xbcdxbr :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KJ xbrcd   :    x: 0.92789, b: 0.07211
KJ xbrcdb  :    f: 0.17405, c: 0.78297, r: 0.04298
KJ xbrcdbr :    f: 0.59715, c: 0.40285
KJ xbrcdx  :    x: 0.66320, b: 0.33680
KJ xbrcdxb :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000, r: 0.00000
KJ xbrcdxbr:    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KJ xxd     :    x: 1.00000, b: 0.00000
KJ xxdb    :    f: 0.99427, c: 0.00100, r: 0.00472
KJ xxdbr   :    f: 0.45040, c: 0.54960
KJ xxdx    :    x: 0.97476, b: 0.02524
KJ xxdxb   :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00000
KJ xxdxbr  :    f: 0.02740, c: 0.97260
KK bcd     :    x: 0.17606, b: 0.82394
KK bcdb    :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
KK bcdbr   :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KK bcdx    :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
KK bcdxb   :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
KK bcdxbr  :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KK brcd    :    x: 0.46435, b: 0.53565
KK brcdb   :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
KK brcdbr  :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KK brcdx   :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
KK brcdxb  :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
KK brcdxbr :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KK xbcd    :    x: 0.90985, b: 0.09015
KK xbcdb   :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.36364, r: 0.63636
KK xbcdbr  :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KK xbcdx   :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
KK xbcdxb  :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
KK xbcdxbr :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KK xbrcd   :    x: 0.00339, b: 0.99661
KK xbrcdb  :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
KK xbrcdbr :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KK xbrcdx  :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
KK xbrcdxb :    f: 0.00002, c: 0.00002, r: 0.99996
KK xbrcdxbr:    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KK xxd     :    x: 0.00185, b: 0.99815
KK xxdb    :    f: 0.00070, c: 0.00284, r: 0.99646
KK xxdbr   :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
KK xxdx    :    x: 0.00105, b: 0.99895
KK xxdxb   :    f: 0.00007, c: 0.00007, r: 0.99986
KK xxdxbr  :    f: 0.00052, c: 0.99948
KQ bcd     :    x: 1.00000, b: 0.00000
KQ bcdb    :    f: 0.70022, c: 0.29978, r: 0.00000
KQ bcdbr   :    f: 0.04903, c: 0.95097
KQ bcdx    :    x: 1.00000, b: 0.00000
KQ bcdxb   :    f: 0.51108, c: 0.48892, r: 0.00000
KQ bcdxbr  :    f: 0.14894, c: 0.85106
KQ brcd    :    x: 0.28412, b: 0.71588
KQ brcdb   :    f: 0.38075, c: 0.53416, r: 0.08509
KQ brcdbr  :    f: 0.60476, c: 0.39524
KQ brcdx   :    x: 0.48603, b: 0.51397
KQ brcdxb  :    f: 0.05516, c: 0.92961, r: 0.01524
KQ brcdxbr :    f: 0.50415, c: 0.49585
KQ xbcd    :    x: 0.10449, b: 0.89551
KQ xbcdb   :    f: 0.57769, c: 0.42231, r: 0.00000
KQ xbcdbr  :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
KQ xbcdx   :    x: 0.64413, b: 0.35587
KQ xbcdxb  :    f: 0.46743, c: 0.53256, r: 0.00001
KQ xbcdxbr :    f: 0.93633, c: 0.06367
KQ xbrcd   :    x: 0.99424, b: 0.00576
KQ xbrcdb  :    f: 0.36345, c: 0.63639, r: 0.00016
KQ xbrcdbr :    f: 0.62087, c: 0.37913
KQ xbrcdx  :    x: 0.39203, b: 0.60797
KQ xbrcdxb :    f: 0.30839, c: 0.68474, r: 0.00687
KQ xbrcdxbr:    f: 0.60775, c: 0.39225
KQ xxd     :    x: 1.00000, b: 0.00000
KQ xxdb    :    f: 0.02112, c: 0.97221, r: 0.00668
KQ xxdbr   :    f: 0.45613, c: 0.54387
KQ xxdx    :    x: 0.97807, b: 0.02193
KQ xxdxb   :    f: 0.57654, c: 0.42346, r: 0.00000
KQ xxdxbr  :    f: 0.04004, c: 0.95996
Q          :    x: 0.25587, b: 0.74413
Q b        :    f: 0.00001, c: 0.63123, r: 0.36877
Q br       :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
Q x        :    x: 0.15089, b: 0.84911
Q xb       :    f: 0.00004, c: 0.84042, r: 0.15954
Q xbr      :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
QJ bcd     :    x: 0.99249, b: 0.00751
QJ bcdb    :    f: 0.98127, c: 0.00000, r: 0.01873
QJ bcdbr   :    f: 0.99999, c: 0.00001
QJ bcdx    :    x: 0.99997, b: 0.00003
QJ bcdxb   :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00000
QJ bcdxbr  :    f: 0.99742, c: 0.00258
QJ brcd    :    x: 1.00000, b: 0.00000
QJ brcdb   :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00000
QJ brcdbr  :    f: 0.47248, c: 0.52752
QJ brcdx   :    x: 0.99999, b: 0.00001
QJ brcdxb  :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00000
QJ brcdxbr :    f: 0.51511, c: 0.48489
QJ xbcd    :    x: 0.97056, b: 0.02944
QJ xbcdb   :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00000
QJ xbcdbr  :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000
QJ xbcdx   :    x: 0.48470, b: 0.51530
QJ xbcdxb  :    f: 0.99768, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00232
QJ xbcdxbr :    f: 0.99648, c: 0.00352
QJ xbrcd   :    x: 0.99403, b: 0.00597
QJ xbrcdb  :    f: 0.97944, c: 0.00000, r: 0.02056
QJ xbrcdbr :    f: 0.99991, c: 0.00009
QJ xbrcdx  :    x: 1.00000, b: 0.00000
QJ xbrcdxb :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00000
QJ xbrcdxbr:    f: 0.99259, c: 0.00741
QJ xxd     :    x: 1.00000, b: 0.00000
QJ xxdb    :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00000
QJ xxdbr   :    f: 0.50000, c: 0.50000
QJ xxdx    :    x: 0.99997, b: 0.00003
QJ xxdxb   :    f: 1.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.00000
QJ xxdxbr  :    f: 0.98653, c: 0.01347
QK bcd     :    x: 0.55301, b: 0.44699
QK bcdb    :    f: 0.70031, c: 0.29969, r: 0.00000
QK bcdbr   :    f: 0.79675, c: 0.20325
QK bcdx    :    x: 0.63095, b: 0.36905
QK bcdxb   :    f: 0.46508, c: 0.52005, r: 0.01487
QK bcdxbr  :    f: 0.99983, c: 0.00017
QK brcd    :    x: 0.87264, b: 0.12736
QK brcdb   :    f: 0.48127, c: 0.51872, r: 0.00002
QK brcdbr  :    f: 0.99997, c: 0.00003
QK brcdx   :    x: 0.57551, b: 0.42449
QK brcdxb  :    f: 0.70575, c: 0.29425, r: 0.00000
QK brcdxbr :    f: 0.92798, c: 0.07202
QK xbcd    :    x: 0.99245, b: 0.00755
QK xbcdb   :    f: 0.55108, c: 0.44886, r: 0.00006
QK xbcdbr  :    f: 0.99999, c: 0.00001
QK xbcdx   :    x: 0.70421, b: 0.29579
QK xbcdxb  :    f: 0.44445, c: 0.55555, r: 0.00000
QK xbcdxbr :    f: 0.99979, c: 0.00021
QK xbrcd   :    x: 0.02677, b: 0.97323
QK xbrcdb  :    f: 0.71842, c: 0.28158, r: 0.00000
QK xbrcdbr :    f: 0.99998, c: 0.00002
QK xbrcdx  :    x: 0.81189, b: 0.18811
QK xbrcdxb :    f: 0.34602, c: 0.65397, r: 0.00001
QK xbrcdxbr:    f: 0.99997, c: 0.00003
QK xxd     :    x: 0.43434, b: 0.56566
QK xxdb    :    f: 0.27018, c: 0.72980, r: 0.00002
QK xxdbr   :    f: 0.88309, c: 0.11691
QK xxdx    :    x: 0.97760, b: 0.02240
QK xxdxb   :    f: 0.00002, c: 0.03786, r: 0.96212
QK xxdxbr  :    f: 0.00002, c: 0.99998
QQ bcd     :    x: 0.49860, b: 0.50140
QQ bcdb    :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
QQ bcdbr   :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
QQ bcdx    :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
QQ bcdxb   :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
QQ bcdxbr  :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
QQ brcd    :    x: 0.01034, b: 0.98966
QQ brcdb   :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
QQ brcdbr  :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
QQ brcdx   :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
QQ brcdxb  :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 0.99999
QQ brcdxbr :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
QQ xbcd    :    x: 0.01234, b: 0.98766
QQ xbcdb   :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.36364, r: 0.63636
QQ xbcdbr  :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
QQ xbcdx   :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
QQ xbcdxb  :    f: 0.00001, c: 0.00001, r: 0.99999
QQ xbcdxbr :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
QQ xbrcd   :    x: 0.95494, b: 0.04506
QQ xbrcdb  :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
QQ xbrcdbr :    f: 0.00001, c: 0.99999
QQ xbrcdx  :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
QQ xbrcdxb :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
QQ xbrcdxbr:    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
QQ xxd     :    x: 0.47380, b: 0.52620
QQ xxdb    :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.26669, r: 0.73331
QQ xxdbr   :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000
QQ xxdx    :    x: 0.00000, b: 1.00000
QQ xxdxb   :    f: 0.00000, c: 0.00000, r: 1.00000
QQ xxdxbr  :    f: 0.00000, c: 1.00000

Where:

First upper-case character indicates the current player's card
Second upper-case character indicates the community card (if dealt)
Actions:

x: check
f: fold
c: call
b: bet
r: raise
d: deal community card



